# Setting log4j properties in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, log4j

I'm trying to set some log4j properties within pyspark, but can't get it to work. For example, I'd like to set the following

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AStorageStatistics=INFO
```

How can I do this in the code? I've tried using extraJavaOptions in SparkConf:

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions",
         "-Dlog4j.debug=true -Dlog4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AStorageStatistics=INFO")
spark_session = SparkSession.builder\
    .config(conf)\
    .getOrCreate()
```

And also in PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = \
            '--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 pyspark-shell ' \
            '--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AStorageStatistics=INFO" -Dlog4j.debug=true'
```

But I don't think either is working as I can't see any S3A statistics in the logs when I read a file from an s3a:// url.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can set/change loglevel within pyspark code

```
logger = spark_session._jvm.org.apache.log4j.LogManager\
    .getLogger("log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AStorageStatistics")
level = spark_session._jvm.org.apache.log4j.Level.toLevel("info")
logger.setLevel(level)
```